# Converting string to 64 bit floats in node.js

Tags: node.js

This question has two inter-related parts which I am deeply struggling with. I just want to point out I have literally been struggling with this for days!

**Part 1**. I have a string of data which is like the following:

```
?\21167\200Z\251\3072\26467\000\350-\306%\33767\240\314\203\310\030\n77\200U\374\307\013577\000@\036\306\376_77\200s\215\307\361\21277\000t\235\306\344\26577\000\204\000\307\327\34077\000\264\217\306\313\01387\000R&\307\276687\000\312\210\306\261a87\000\364\026\306\244\21487p\257\"\311\227\26787\000@U\306\212\34287\000\324\210\306}\r97\000\274*\306p897\000\270\016\306J\27197\000\250u\306=\34497\000\224r\3060\017:7\000\316\213\306#::7@\254\223\310\026e:7\000d\251\306\374\272:7\000(-\306\360\345:7\000\322\202\306\343\020;7\200D\230\307\311f;7\000\\\314\306\274\221;7\0000\246\306\257\274;7\000\230\342\305\242\347;7\000\000\220\310\225\022<7\0002\003\307\210=<7\200X\316\307|h<7\000-\033\307o\223<7\000\000\367\305b\276<7\000|\237\306U\351<7\000Di\306H\024=7\000\356>\307;?=7\000\024u\306!\225=7\240J\317\310\025\300=7\000\224@\306\010\353=7\000\373\027\307\373\025>7\0008p\310\324\226>7\000\360\205\306\272\354>7\000\226m\307\255\027?7\000\224\304\306\241B?7\200D\240\310\224m?7\000\304x\306\207\230?7\000B\337\306z\303?7\000;\217\307`\031@7\000\252q\307SD@7\000\244d\3069\232@7\000\270\324\306-\305@7\200\311\266\307 \360@7\340P\233\310\023\033A7\000\014\245\307\006FA7\000B\324\307\371pA7\000\362\002\307\354\233A7\000L@\306\337\306A7\000$\031\306\322\361A7\000\002\004\307\306\034B7\000,U\306\254rB7\000\274\341\306\237\235B7 W\212\310\222\310B7\000\177N\307\205\363B7\0004\351\306x\036C7\000\004\037\306kIC7@;f\310^tC7\000\371Q\307E\312C7\000$f\3078\365C7\000\032\320\306+ D7\000\226\252\306\036KD7\200\350\216\310\021vD7\000\270?\306\367\313D7\000@\032\306\353\366D7\200\2100\310\336!E7\000\270[\306\321LE7\000\"{\307\304wE7\000^\301\306\267\242E7\000\246\240\306\252\315E7\000b\006\307\235\370E7\200\003M\311\220#F7\000\374\203\306\203NF7\000T{\306wyF7\000PT\306j\244F7\000\364^\306]\317F7\000\324\003\307P\372F7\000\303 \307K^67\000\204\000\306X367\000\324\341\306e\01067\000\271\001\307r\33557\000\374\004\306\177\26257\000\240\235\305\214\20757\000\217\242\307\231\\57\000PS\306\246157 \013\236\310\262\00657\000 \222\307\277\33347\000\244\210\306\314\26047\000\226\353\306\346Z47\200\257P\310\331\20547\000\213M\307\363/47\000$\021\306\000\00547\000\373\241\307\r\33237\000z\355\307\032\25737\000\010\244\306&\20437\000\271p\3103Y37\000\307f\307@.37\000\241^\307M\00337\000l&\306Z\33027\000\226\213\306g\25527\000fx\307t\20227\300\352\020\310\201W27\000\253\231\307\215,27\000v\267\306\247\32617@\373r\310\264\25317\000X\202\305\301\20017\300\357\020\310\316U17\000\016\227\306\333*17\000\030\010\307\350\37707\300XN\310\365\32407\000\350U\306\001\25207\000\344\363\306\016\17707\200\324\360\307\033T07\000\022\"\307()07 \213\375\3105\376/7\000\265\222\307O\250/7\000\251r\307B\323/7\200O\215\307\\}/7\200\235\376\307iR/7\000\324\274\307\202\374.7\000S*\307u\'/7\000R-\307\217\321.7\000j\177\307\234\246.7\200)\346\307\251{.7\000\364\350\307\266P.7\000!\310\307\303%.7\000-/\307\320\372-7\200\'\207\307\334\317-7\300\357\006\310\351\244-7\000$(\310\366y-7\000\177:\307\003O-7\200t\361\307\020$-7\0001\217\307\035\371,7\000`G\305*\316,7\200\t3\3107\243,7\300\022\017\310Dx,7\000\244m\307PM,7\000\327o\307]\",7\000\004s\307j\367+7 \360\257\310w\314+7\000\265;\307\204\241+7\000D2\306\221v+7\000\261`\307\236K+7\000 \313\306\253 +7 \337!\311\267\365*7@6L\310\304\312*7\000\271;\310\321\237*7\000%\205\307\336t*7\000\0145\307\353I*7\200E\242\307\370\036*7\000~E\307\005\364)7\000\311\031\307\022\311)7\000\302\374\307\037\236)7\200\276\t\310+s)7\000\261Z\3108H)7\200\350\325\307E\035)7\240\321\201\310R\362(7\000\276\334\307_\307(7\000\246\016\310l\234(7\300\006\254\310yq(7\000\266\024\310\206F(7\200Q2\310\223\033(7\200d\235\307\237\360\'7\000\311\314\307\254\305\'7@i\250\310\271\232\'7\300\254Y\310\306o\'7@\260\t\310\323D\'7\000\336\232\307\340\031\'7\000w&\307\355\356&7\360\226\017\311\372\303&7\000\240\226\306\006\231&7\200\253Q\310\023n&7@OT\310 C&7\000\034&\310-\030&7\000\213d\310:\355%7\000\000\200\302\363\202\0317\000\031\273G\000X\0317\000\246\276G\r-\0317\000\314\271F\032\002\0317\000\242\037G\'\327\0307\200\334\237G4\254\0307\3401\260HA\201\0307\000\262\307FNV\0307\000\230_FZ+\0307\000\022\256Fg\000\0307\200\354\232Gt\325\0277\000\246\355F\201\252\0277\000\336\355F\216\177\0277\000:$G\233T\0277\000\324jF\250)\0277\000\273\231G\265\376\0267p\365\031I\302\323\0267\000j\240G\333}\0267\000\370\247E\350R\0267\000tbF\365\'\0267\000Q7G\034\247\0257\000\304\036F)|\0257\000\214mF5Q\0257`\254\203HB&\0257\000\213|GO\373\0247\000o#Hi\245\0247\000\026\213Fvz\0247\000\014\346F\203O\0247\000\277\236G\220$\0247\000\014\214F\235\371\0237\200\355\345G\251\316\0237\000\312\253F\266\243\0237\200\001\203G\303x\0237\200\034\206G\320M\0237\000\030\236G\335\"\0237@x\033H\352\367\0227\000\3630G\367\314\0227\000>\260F\004\242\0227\000|\242F\021w\0227\000\240uH\035L\0227\000Z\005G7\366\0217\000\':GQ\240\0217\000-\tGkJ\0217\000\340LFx\037\0217\000\224\316F\204\364\0207\000\270\365F\221\311\0207\000\004\332F\236\236\0207\000\224\021G\253s\0207\000\334UG\270H\0207\000\274\211F\305\035\0207\200\243\353G\337\307\0177\000z\037H\370q\0177\000\t3G\022\034\0177\000\335<G\037\361\0167@\275+H,\306\0167\200\323\272G9\233\0167\300\030)HSE\0167\000\026\237F_\032\0167\000L\227Fl\357\r7\000~\243Fy\304\r7\000\306\037G\206\231\r7\000\334XF\240C\r7\000 dF\272\355\0147\000\374\324F\307\302\0147\000\014\207F\340l\0147\000\327CG\372\026\0147\000\370\261F\007\354\0137\000\025\003G\024\301\0137@ \\H!\226\0137\000\254\247F.k\0137\000\024\270F;@\0137\000\362\216Fa\277\n7\000\020\023F{i\n7\000(\033G\347\255\0317\0008\226E\332\330\0317\000\000\276F\315\003\0327\000\230\253E\300.\0327\000XEF\263Y\0327\000cSH\246\204\0327\200`\224G\231\257\0327\000\366\337G\214\332\0327\000P\353Es0\0337\000&\212Ff[\0337\000\263JGY\206\0337\000\212gG?\334\0337\200\260\202GL\261\0337\000\324PF2\007\0347\340\023\037I%2\0347\000\256\314F\030]\0347\000\250#F\013\210\0347\000<\251G\377\262\0347\000\320hE\362\335\0347\000\270nF\3303\0357\200\263\327G\313^\0357\000\016\227F\276\211\0357\200\313\244G\261\264\0357\0005\262G\244\337\0357\200\307\301G\230\n\0367\2001\200G\2135\0367\000\020:F~`\0367\200\330\234Gq\213\0367\200\222\314Gd\266\0367\000\357BGW\341\0367\000\240\234FJ\014\0377\200\025\332G=7\0377\000d\021F0b\0377\000dhH$\215\0377\000\002iG\027\270\0377\200[\246G\n\343\0377\200e\264G\375\r 7\000 2G\3608 7\000@\302E\343c 7\200y\250G\326\216 7\000\335DG\311\271 7\000\323\263G\275\344 7\000B\214F\260\017!7\200\246\243G\226e!7\0006`G\243:!7\200\036\344G\211\220!7\200u\371G|\273!7\000\340\202Go\346!7\000\272\377Fb\021\"7@v<HU<\"7\000\"\330FIg\"7\000\004FG<\222\"7\200;\271G/\275\"7\200C\243H\"\350\"7\000\370\337F\025\023#7\300\r\001H\010>#7\000\215^H\373h#7\200K\202G\356\223#7\000\236\350G\341\276#7\200k\303G\325\351#7\000F\346G\310\024$7\3002\030H\273?$7\200\220\276G\241\225$7`d\371H\256j$7\240\275\036I\224\300$7@y\036H\207\353$7\000@\237Gz\026%7\000^<Gal%7\200^?HnA%7\2000\231HT\227%7\200\310\323GG\302%7\300+DH
```

I am reading data from a file and I end up with a variable `myString` with the above data in it. When I do `typeof` on it, it says it's a `string` and when I do a `console.log` on it, it outputs the above exactly.So I created a new node.js file, and put all of the data above inside quotes:

`newString = "?\21167\200Z\251\3072\26467\000 etc"`

When I `console.log(newString)` it outputs

```
?‰67€Z©Ç2´67è-Æ%ß67 Ìƒ77€UüÇ 577ÉÆþ_77€sÇñŠ77tÆäµ77„Ç×à7 etc
```

Rather than the original string `"?\21167\200Z\251\3072\26467\000..."` etc

What is going on here?

**Part 2**. Because of 1 I have struggled to to extract the 64 bit floats from this string.

I can do it Python!:

```
import numpy as np
data_new = b"?\21167\200Z\251\3072\26467\000\350-\306%\33767\240\314\2  etc etc"
print(np.frombuffer(data_new, dtype="f4,f4"))
```

Is there an easy way to do this in node?

Comment: I think the issue here is that "\" acts as an escape character and that messes with your string. You may need to double escape it ("\\"). Another issue that I could think of is the encoding. Perhaps it is not the right encoding? (utf-8, utf-16).

Comment: @lanxion You're right about the escape character. Any idea how to do the conversation to 64 bit floating numbers?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

In JavaScript, `\<OCTAL SEQUENCE>` [inside a string literal](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#octal) will give you the Unicode character represented by that codepoint in octal. This feature is deprecated in modern JavaScript but still works for backward-compatibility reasons (except in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where it throws a `SyntaxError`).

The octal sequence must be in the range `0o0..0o377` (decimal `0..255` or hexadecimal `0x0..0xff`) for this to happen.

```js
'\1'.codePointAt(0).toString(16) // 1
String.fromCodePoint(0x01) // <Start of Heading>
// https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0001

'\377'.codePointAt(0).toString(16) // ff
String.fromCodePoint(0xff) // "ÿ"
```

If the number *isn't* valid Octal, the backslash is simply "swallowed":

```js
'\9'.codePointAt(0).toString(16) // 39
String.fromCodePoint(0x39) // "9"
// 9 is not a valid octal number, so the string
// simply evaluates to the character "9"
```

### Solutions

#### Option 1

Replace all the backslashes `\` with double-backslashes `\\` to escape them, then you should be good to go.

```js
'\\1'.codePointAt(0).toString(16) // 5c
String.fromCodePoint(0x5c) // Reverse Solidus (AKA backslash)
// https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+005C
```

#### Option 2

Use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) with a template literal.

```js
String.raw`\1\2\3` === "\\1\\2\\3" // true
```

Note that this will not work if there is a backslash at the *very end* of the string:

```js
String.raw`\` // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: I have tried this: 
console.log(String.raw`${myString}`); where var myString is defined as in my question and I still get the same output as before. The same also happens with newString.

Comment: Also, do you have any ideas about converting the string into 64bit floats, as in my Python code? Thank you for any help

Comment: `const str = '\1'; String.raw\`${str}\`` will fail. You need to use `const str = String.raw\`\1\`` (i.e. write it literally inside the backticks when assigning).

Comment: Regarding your second question, it's not really related, so I'd recommend making a separate StackOverflow question about it (after searching to see if it's already been answered).

Comment: I need to be able to pass variables in as I'm reading data from a file, as per the question. It's fine for a proof of concept but it's unfortunately not practical for me to manually copy/paste it in!

Comment: If you're reading from a file, you shouldn't need to worry about backslash escaping at all. If `file` has literal contents `\1\2\3`, then `fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8') === '\\1\\2\\3'`.

Comment: I see. In that case then I just need to know how to convert that string to 64 bit floats, as per the question title, then I'm done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220983/discussion-between-lionel-rowe-and-fachtna-simi).

Comment: @FachtnaSimi Be careful here. A `\ ` read from a file **is not treated as an escape character** as in this answer. The `\ ` is only an escape character in **source code**. Be sure you understand the difference between string syntax in source code and strings as read from a file

Comment: @slebetman Yeah I think I may have misunderstood based on the quoted code in OP (`newString = "..."`).

Comment: @LionelRowe I cracked this in the end... in a nutshell, the trick was to replace all octal escape sequences with a string created from the codepoint (fromCodePoint). Well that mostly solved it, then I had to do a few other replacements.Then it works perfectly.